# What version of TLS is supported by BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I am trying to find what is the default  implementation of BlackBerry for TLS protocol. Does it default to 1.0 or 1.1 or 1.2.

I am trying to find 1. What versions are TLS are supported 2. What is the default?
I have an app on BB world that connects to a back office server. The server team has decided to deprecate TLSv1.0. I am trying to find if this will impact my customers?

Comment: What do you mean? Normally this is negotiated.

Comment: Please look at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2287/_index.html

Comment: Why exactly would I go out and go read some external thing?

Comment: Put all necessary information in your question body.

Comment: updated the question above

Comment: I found this documentation 
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html
It sounds like BB doesn't support TLS v1.1 or 1.2 ...surprising

Comment: The document you linked to is for Java development on BlackBerry OS 5.0, which predates 6.0 and 7.0, which all predate BB10.

Answer (score 1):

Current versions of BB10 do indeed support TLS 1.2 which you can test by using tools provided by [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/). Unfortunately that is not the end of the story.

TLS is a protocol which specifies how to set up and use an encrypted connection. It does not set absolute requirements on encryption algorithm support however. I am aware of one documented case of an issue connecting with some Exchange Active Sync servers because the BB10 device and the server as configured do not have any cypher suites in common. Other EAS servers that are configured differently do not present this issue to BB10 devices.

What you need to do is find out specifically how the server team is going to configure TLS, and what they are going to accept for connections.